# How do i hold the correct output value without roundoff the double value in given program

Tags: c#, operators, rounding, user-defined-data-types

Given the meal price (base cost of a meal), tip percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tip), and tax percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tax) for a meal, find and print the meal's total cost.

Condition: Be sure to use precise values for your calculations, or you may end up with an incorrectly rounded result!

Here is my Program:

```C#
static void Main(String[] args)    
{

    double mealCost=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    int tipPercent=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    int taxPercent=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    double tip,tax;

    tip=(mealCost*(tipPercent/100));

    tax=(mealCost*(taxPercent/100));

    double totalCost=mealCost+tip+tax;

    Console.WriteLine("The total meal cost is {0} dollars",totalCost);

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

But I had the output as 12.

My  Expected output is 15.

If my  sample input is 12.00 20 8

My  calculation as `tip=2.4` and `tax=0.96`, `totalCost=15.36`
and the rounded value is
`(round)totalCost=15`.

But the output came as 12.

How do I get the correct output in C#. Can anyone provide me some suggestions to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is, take `tipPercent` and `taxPercent` as double values or else implicitly convert them to double before processing division like the following:

```
tip = (mealCost * ((double)tipPercent / 100));
tax = (mealCost * ((double)taxPercent / 100));
```

Then you will get `totalCost=15.36` for the input specified in the question. Much smarter solution is :

```
 double mealCost, tipPercent, taxPercent;
 Console.WriteLine("Enter values for Meal Cost, Tip percentage and tax percentage");
 if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out mealCost))
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid input for meal Cost");
 }
 if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tipPercent))
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid input for Tip percentage");
 }

 if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out taxPercent))
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid input for Tip tax Percent");
 }
 double tip = (mealCost * (tipPercent / 100));
 double tax = (mealCost * (taxPercent / 100));
 double totalCost = mealCost + tip + tax;
 Console.WriteLine("The total meal cost is {0}", totalCost.ToString("C0"));

 Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: thank you for your comment..it works great. but after the totalCost ,i have to round the value

Answer (score 1):

First, please change your data type to `decimal` instead of `double`, more suitable for money related.

Second, when you do the calculation, C# will try to return with the same data type, which caused:

```
tip=(mealCost*(tipPercent/100));    // it will turn tipPercent/100 to int, which is 0
tax=(mealCost*(taxPercent/100));    // same here
```

You have many way to do it, like cast as double:

```
tip = (mealCost * ((double) tipPercent / 100));
```

State the `100` to `100D` (tell c# it is double)

```
tip = (meanCost * (tipPercent / 100D));
```

Or, just use double / decimal for your `tipPercent` and `taxPercent`

```
double tipPercent = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

in division you should have at least one double to get answer in double  very less change you need to make it work see bellow

```
static void Main(String[] args) 
{
double mealCost=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

int tipPercent=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int taxPercent=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

double tip,tax;

tip=(mealCost*(tipPercent/100.0));//change 100 to 100.0

tax=(mealCost*(taxPercent/100.0));//change 100 to 100.0

double totalCost=mealCost+tip+tax;

Console.WriteLine("The total meal cost is {0} dollars",totalCost);

Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `0` since you code divide an `int` value by an `int` value. The  division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the absolute value of the quotient of the two operands. You can review how C# handles it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373(v=vs.71).aspx).

If you rewrite your tip, tax calculation with following.

```
 tip = (mealCost * tipPercent / 100);
 tax = (mealCost * taxPercent / 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to this two lines:

```
 tip=(mealCost*(tipPercent/100));

 tax=(mealCost*(taxPercent/100));
```

These define operations between integer and will return integers. Cast to double or declare 100 as double like this: `100d`